# Unable to pass parameters to service hook through find function in featherjs

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, feathersjs, feathers-hook

Featherjs find service unable to pass extra parameters through find function. In below find service passing extra params data to service.
but unable to receive the value at service hook.

Client code :

```
return this.app.service('userlist').find({
      query: { usersIds: { "$in" : [this.user._id]} },
      paginate: false,
      params:{ name:'sam' }
    }).then(response => {


}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Server code (Service hook ) :

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) { 
return async function dogetUsr (context) {
    const { data } = context;

    console.log('Client Param data -->',context.params.name);

    return context;
  };
};
```

params data not receiving at server -->
            `params:{ name:'sam' }`

Output at server/service hook :

```
Client Param data -->undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, only `params.query` is passed between the client and the server. In general I wouldn't recommend letting the client disable pagination unless you are guaranteed to only get a few (less than 100) records. Otherwise requests with many records can cause major issues on both sides.

If it is still something you need, you can use the [disablePagination](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/#disablepagination) hook which lets you set the `$limit` to `-1` if you want to disable pagination:

```
const { disablePagination } = require('feathers-hooks-common');
module.exports = { before: {
  find: disablePagination()
} };
```

Comment: Actually pagination is not my concern.we want to pass extra parameters in find service . please share how to pass extra params from client to server through find service/function .

Comment: This is already explained in the FAQ at https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#why-cant-i-pass-params-from-the-client